# Model field in AROs table not prefixing plugin name

Tags: cakephp, acl, cakephp-2.3

Currently I have setup the Auth & ACL components in a CakePHP App. I have a `Group` & `User` model both setup to act as the requester. This all worked fine to begin with, the `aros` table was updating properly whenever a new Group was added. For example, this would be my contents of the `aros` table:

```
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
| id | parent_id | model | foreign_key | alias | lft  | rght |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
|  1 |      NULL | Group |           1 | NULL  |    1 |    2 |
|  2 |      NULL | Group |           2 | NULL  |    3 |    4 |
|  3 |      NULL | Group |           3 | NULL  |    5 |    6 |
+----+-----------+-------+-------------+-------+------+------+
```

I have since refactored out the `User` and `Group` model's into their own plugin called 'Survey' (along with other models, controllers, components, etc..).

I immediately got this error:

```
AclNode::node() - Couldn't find Aro node identified by "Array ( [Aro0.model] => Group [Aro0.foreign_key] => 1 ) "
```

I updated the `User::bindNode()` method to include the 'Survey' prefix on the model:

```
class User extends SurveyAppModel
{
    // ...

    public function bindNode($user)
    {
        return array('model' => 'Survey.Group', 'foreign_key' => $user['Survey.User']['group_id']);
    }

    //...
}
```

I have also changed the 'model' field in the `aros` table to be 'Survey.Group' instead of 'Group'.

This then removed the error and my authorisation and authentication was working again. My problem now happens when I save a new record to the Group model, the model field in the `aros` table is is set to 'Group' and not 'Survey.Group' so I then get the same error as before.

So I'm wondering how I can get it so that when I save a new record to the Group model it automatically adds the plugin prefix name to 'model' field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this by setting the `$name` property of the Group model and prefixing it with the plugin name. You also need to set the `$useTable` property as if you don't it will look for a table named `my_plugin.my_model`.

For example, this is what I now have set in my Group model which is a part of the 'Survey' plugin.

```
class Group extends SurveyAppModel
{
    // ...

    public $name = 'Survey.Group';

    public $useTable = 'groups';

    // ...
}
```

I discovered this by looking through the `AclBehavior::afterSave()` method, in there it saves a record to the `aros` table and uses the `$model->name` property for the model field.